# Java.Build-Path.Classpath-Variables Deprecated: Use Java-Releated Library Instead

Tags: java, eclipse, deprecated, buildpath, eclipse-classpath

## What are the details of your problem?

Java Build-Path Classpath-Variables are being marked as deprecated for JDK-11 on Eclipse-Preferences. I'm not sure if I can or how-to-fix these kind of warnings being raised. We're required to use a specific version of Eclipse and Java now. I'm coming from using IntelliJ so I'm not familiar if this setup is not correct.

```
JRE_LIB is deprecated: Use the JRE System Library instead. 
JRE_SRC is deprecated: Use the JRE System Library instead. 
JRE_SRCROTT is deprecated: Use the JRE System Library instead. 
JUNIT_HOME is deprecated: Use the JUNIT Library instead.
```

Can I fix this warning? Or is this just a general disclaimer? If this can get fixed, how?

```
JRE_LIB (non modifiable, deprecated) - X:\...\Java\jdk-11.x.x.x\lib\jrt-fs.jar)
JRE_SRC (non modifiable, deprecated) - X:\...\Java\jdk-11.x.x.x\lib\src.jar)
JRE_SRCROOT (non modifiable, deprecated) - (empty)
JRE_LIB (non modifiable, deprecated) - X:\...\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.x.x.vYYYYMMDD-NNNN.jar)
```

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

I tried adding `New...` and no options presented themselves for the `JRE System Library` to select.
I couldn't `Remove` or `Edit...` any of these options. The buttons were grayed on selection.
And, I didn't find any `Quick Fix` or other recommendations to select through. I can't switch off using the prescribed JDK - so not only can I not install but I'm not allowed to use another alternative.

Comment: There is no need to deal with these variables in the first place. Just create a new project and select an execution environment for the intended target Java version. When you set up a project that way, you will never stumble over these variables. I don’t know how to fix the setup you have now, as I have no idea what you did before, to run into the problem.

Comment: inspect your `.project` file (with external editor) ...

Comment: @Holger I can't create a new project, as this isn't my place to decide such.

Comment: @xerx593 I did inspect it, is there anything I'm supposed to lookout for? I only see `buildSpect.buildCommand` and `natures.nature` options found. Build-Commands: `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder`, `org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder`. Natures: `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature`, `org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature`.

Comment: I didn’t meant to say that you have to create a new project. The point is, these variables are deprecated since more the fifteen years now; this has nothing to do with JDK-11. So either, these projects are ancient or someone tried really hard to create projects in a non-standard way. Go to the project properties, then to the Java Build Path and remove all these entries. Then, if there is no “JRE System Library” entry already, click on Classpath for target <=8 or Modulepath for >=9 and click on “Add Library…” and select “JRE System Library”.

Comment: pardon, then please also inspect `.classpath` (file) (I suspect the "lib definitions" there...)